# login page doesn't show invalidation message

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils.text import capfirst
from .models import Classname, Sectionname, Teachername, Attendancename

class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': ("Please enter a correct %(username)s and password."
                          "Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."),
        'inactive': ("This account is inactive"),
    }

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if username and password:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if self.user_cache is None:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
                    code='invalid_login',
                )

        return self.cleaned_data

    def confirm_login_allowed(self, request):
        if self.user_cache.is_active:
            login(request, self.user_cache)
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['inactive'],
                code='inactive',
                )

    def get_user_id(self):
        if self.user_cache:
            return self.user_cache.id
        return None

    def get_user(self):
        return self.user_cache
```

views.py:

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.confirm_login_allowed(request)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('student:mains'))
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form},)
```

my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Is anyone getting tired of repeatedly entering the header over and over?? -->
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Login to Mysite</h1>

        <form id="login_form" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />
            <br />
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" size="50" />
            <br />
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

I'm working on django-auth forms and views and trying to implement on my current small app. Everything works fine except when I provide incorrect credentials, then form doesn't raise any error.

In spite of that it remains on same login page without any appropriate message.

However I've defined `'raise ValidatonError'` in my form's `'confirm_login_allowed'` method and in my views also `'print(form.errors)'`.

I don't know why does it not showing appropriate messages.

Can anybody have idea where I'm doing wrong?

Thanks! in advance.....

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the Django registration redux package? Edit: You also didn't add `{{ field.errors }}`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're never using the {'form': form} in your template, and instead have chosen to build the two inputs manually. This actually works in kicking off all the backend processes that you'd want with regards to authentication because you've assigned the name values of each form element to correspond with the Variables in AuthenticationForm (i.e. username, password). So everything works accordingly on POST. But on GET, you're never actually using the form.error_message, so there's no place to display it, even if it gets assigned a value.